# Npm -g List shows the version I have installed but doesn't show me the latest available

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been using bower which follows a similar syntax to NPM, so if i do

```
  Bower list
```

It shows me a list of the installed packaged but also tells me if there is a higher version available.

I tried the npm -g list and I see a number of packages which I know there are updates available but it doesn't say update available.

I tried offering --depth=0 and still the same.

I didn't want to just run update as this would install all updates and I have seen before breaking changes from 1 version to another.

I am probably not using npm correctly, is there a way to a get a list of what I have installed and what is available together so I can see it on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for **npm outdated**:

this  command  will  check  the registry to see if any (or, specific) installed packages are currently outdated.

> npm outdated -g

Here is the output example:

```
npm@1.3.13 /Users/miktam/.nvm/v0.10.20/lib/node_modules/npm current=1.3.11
```

Comment: Thats great, just what I needed. Thanks